# Javascript: emulating maxWidth and maxHeight for images in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, css

I need to use maxWidth and maxHeight for images in a script that needs to work with IE 7/8. Since IE does not support these CSS rules, I wrote the following function:

```
function maxDimensions(element, maxWidth, maxHeight)
{
    element.style.width = 'auto';
    element.style.height = 'auto';
    element.style.width = maxWidth;
    var ht = element.innerHeight ? element.innerHeight : element.clientHeight;
    if (ht > maxHeight)
    {
        element.style.width = 'auto';
        element.style.height = maxHeight;
    }
}
```

However, this seems to fail silently and simply not resize some images, while work perfectly fine on others. Is there an "accepted" way of getting this done in IE? And is there anything obviously wrong with my code?

Comment: Since when does `min-width` and `max-width` not work with IE7/8 ? It's IE6 that doesn't support those properties.

Comment: I'm working in Javascript here, and IE 7/8 are not accepting maxWidth and maxHeight like firefox / safari do

Comment: Are you working in JavaScript purely because you can't get the CSS properties working? Or are you working in JavaScript for some other reason? Both IE7/8 do support the CSS properties `min-width` and `max-width`.

Comment: I am working with javascript because this is happening in a bookmarklet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emulate maxWidth and maxHeight in IE6 using CSS expressions - example here http://www.cameronmoll.com/archives/000892.html. Make sure you conditionally apply these rules to target only IE6 and keep in mind that CSS expressions have some big performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, i'm looking for a JS solution in IE 7 and 8 (ele.style.maxWidth and ele.style.maxHeight don't seem to do anything at all)

Comment: his answer is correct.  Read the page.  You don't set maxWidth in IE, you set width.  Set it to "expression(...)" if you want.

Comment: I did read the page. My code `imagepreview.style.width = expression(document.body.clientWidth > 100 ? '100px' : document.body.clientWidth);` errors with "Object Expected"

Comment: `imagepreview.style.width = "expression(document.body.clientWidth > 100 ? '100px' : document.body.clientWidth);"`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know you needed the quotes. Anyway, the above errors with "Invalid Argument" :-\ I'll double check to make sure I copied the page correctly

Comment: yeah no dice :( not even using *exactly* the code on the page (JS-ified like you suggested)

Comment: damn IE.  Try `imagepreview.style.setExpression('width', "Math.min(document.body.clientWidth, 100) + 'px'");`

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [jQMinMax](http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-minmax/) plugin.

Edit: OP has added that this is for a bookmarklet, so this won't work in that case.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a Javascript solution, not a jQuery solution

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but the bookmarklet context was not given when I answered this question.

Comment: jQuery IS javascript, and fixes a lot of cross browser compatibility issues.

Comment: jQuery is written in Javascript, but is most certainly not Javascript

Comment: Of course it is. :-/ When you are writing code using the jQuery library, you are writing JavaScript. It's true that it's not "vanilla" JavaScript, but it *IS* JavaScript. The OP didn't clarify until after the question was initially posted, and even if the answer is not acceptable to the OP, that's no reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the bug in the code I posted:

```
element.style.width = maxWidth;
```

should read

```
element.style.width = maxWidth+"px";
```

(and similarly for style.height). As such, the function on the question should read:

```
function maxDimensions(element, maxWidth, maxHeight)
{
    element.style.width = 'auto';
    element.style.height = 'auto';
    element.style.width = maxWidth+"px";
    var ht = element.innerHeight ? element.innerHeight : element.clientHeight;
    if (ht > maxHeight)
    {
        element.style.width = 'auto';
        element.style.height = maxHeight+"px";
    }

}
```

This now works. However, I'm leaving the question open for now in case someone has a working simpler solution.